# count similar and dissimilar values in two columns with different size

Tags: r

To be honest, I cannot figure out how to do this

```
df <-structure(list(d1 = 1:5, d2 = c(3L, 4L, 6L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("d1", 
"d2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

This is the df

```
d1  d2
1   3
2   4
3   6
4   
5
```

I want to know which and how many of d2 and d1 are similar `which the answer is:`

> 2 values are similar and they are 3,4

I want to know how many and which ones from d2 are dissimilar to d1 `which the answer is:`

> 1 value and 6

and finally I want to know which and how many of d1 are dissimilar to d2 `which again the answer is:`

> 3 values and 1,2,5

is there someone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setdiff()` and `intersect()`:

```
intersect(df$d1, df$d2)
# [1] 3 4
setdiff(df$d2, df$d1)
# [1]  6 NA
setdiff(df$d1, df$d2)
# [1] 1 2 5
```

Comment: seems it does it, is it possible to have the count too? like the first one 2, the second 1 and the third 3?

Comment: @nik  use the length() function.  length() tells you how many atomic elements are in each vector

Comment: @hackR I liked and accept. this took few hours of my life !!! thanks